# mysql how to query total returned rows in group by situation

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sum

I am stuck on a mysql query, I want a new column (total rows) to show the total of returned rows, so e.g the return rows are 5, I want every column (total rows) to display 5 in each single row. However, when I do a group by in the same query, it splits it and displays 1 in each instead. How do I make it so that it does not get bothered by the "group by", maybe a sum of the count?

My original query I tried that failed:

```
select  curdate() as todays_date, qty as Quantity, plu as Item_ID, item as Description,
sum(count(distinct plu)) from transact where qdate  between '2013-07-01' and '2014-07-10'
and location ='8' group by plu;
```

the sum(count(distinct plu)) would not work, any query that will perform the same function?

Thanks

EDIT:

here are some results from the query.

```
'2014-08-08', '6', '1', '', 'MUM NAME RIBBON', '1'
'2014-08-08', '8', '1', '698-1284C-01-AS', 'Fearless Friar Sweatshirts AS', '1'
'2014-08-08', '8', '1', '698-1584-01-L', 'Shield Sweatshirts (new & old) L', '1'
'2014-08-08', '8', '1', '718103072885', 'Composition Book', '1'
'2014-08-08', '8', '1', '93546AS', 'Sweatshirt - Grey Friars - AS', '1'
'2014-08-08', '4', '1', 'AA01', 'Girls Soccer Game Ticket', '1'
'2014-08-08', '4', '1', 'AA04', 'BASEBALL HATS', '1'
'2014-08-08', '4', '1', 'AA06', 'BASKETBALL FEES', '1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do a count inside a sum in one query.. that is invalid syntax.. but for what you want to do you need a separate query by itself that does the count and is not affected by the original query like so:

```
SELECT 
    t.todays_date, t.Quantity, t.Item_ID, t.Description, t1.num_plu
FROM
(   SELECT  
        CURDATE() AS todays_date, 
        qty AS Quantity, 
        plu AS Item_ID, 
        item AS Description 
    FROM transact 
    WHERE qdate  BETWEEN ('2013-07-01' AND '2014-07-10')
      AND location ='8' 
    GROUP BY counter
) t
JOIN
(   SELECT
        plu, COUNT(DISTINCT plu) AS num_rows
    FROM transact
    WHERE qdate  BETWEEN ('2013-07-01' AND '2014-07-10')
      AND location ='8' 
) t1 on t1.plu = t.Item_ID
```

[SEE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88b09/1)

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your response.
I see you edited it a while ago, when I tried your first time's query it seems right however, it returned a total of 275 rows but each row under num_plu I still only get value of 1, I was hoping to get 275 in each single 275 rows.
I just tried your edited query, however, this one does not seem to get grouped by PLU, it only returns me 1 row with total value of 275. thanks

Comment: @PolandSpring hey no problem! does my solution make sense to you? i'd appreciate a +1 if you would like to trow one my way ;)

Comment: I see you edited it a while ago, when I tried your first time's query it seems right however, it returned a total of 275 rows but each row under num_plu I still only get value of 1, I was hoping to get 275 in each single 275 rows. I just tried your edited query, however, this one does not seem to get grouped by PLU, it only returns me 1 row with total value of 275. thanks

Comment: @PolandSpring try running that query -- if it doesnt work then I need you to post some data.. so that way I can reproduce your error

Comment: It still returns only 1 row, the first query you had was more similar in that it returns everything, except it still splits up the sum count of total rows returned.

Comment: yea the first query will not do what you want. can you post some data please? that way I can replicate the issue you have here. just like 5 rows of data is plenty

Comment: I added some data to another response by myself, these are the returned rows from the first query you wrote

Comment: @PolandSpring ok can you tell me if there is a unique identifier on the table? like an ID for each row? not the plu since that has duplicates

Comment: Yes, there is a column called counter that is the PK but I did not include it since I am not trying to use it, but I thought it should work since I did distinct plu

Comment: @PolandSpring if you notice the plu is 1 for multiple columns... you need to join this on the unique identifier.. here i'll edit the query with that and it'll work properly

Comment: @PolandSpring ok i just edited my answer.. that should do the trick

Comment: @PolandSpring actually i just edited again.. that query should work.. I just tested locally and it worked -- i added a sqlfiddle link so you can see it in action.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88b09/1

Comment: I think that did the trick a little, however, I need to have it group based by the PLU, but if you do group by PLU doesnt it automatically make it unique? And although it does return the total rows here it returns total rows of entire table, not the ones returned.

Comment: @PolandSpring ok so change the count back to DISTINCT plu.. and group by plu wont show all rows because its just 1.. so if you have 8 rows where the plu is 1 then you will only have 1 row returned because the value is the same in the groupby. i'll edit my question.